# tomcat prompts for basic login after successfull Siteminder SSO webagent authentication

Tags: authentication, authorization, tomcat7, single-sign-on, siteminder

I Have a basic apache2.4 HTTP webserver and tomcat7 application server.
CA Siteminder Webagent is configured in HTTP Webserver and passing traffic to application server using mod_proxy.
when user successfully login to SSO and passing the request to webapplication deployed in tomcat is asking for standard tomcat login.

how to stop asking tomcat standard login and how  to pass the roles to application while authentication happens using siteminder webagent.

we are working default tomcat manager web application and we are trying to enable SSO using Siteminder Web Agent.

I have gone through this.. https://communities.ca.com/thread/97599955#comment-97600618
but I dont know how roles will pass to application.

Comment: https://comm.support.ca.com/kb/how-to-protect-a-tomcat-web-application-using-siteminder/kb000053831#/

Answer (score 0):

The short answer is that there is no way in your current setup to assert a J2EE principal. When using a reverse proxy your application has to look at the SM http request headers to determine the user identity and roles (via SM responses).

Your options here are:

1. change the application to look for headers instead of J2EE security
   constraints (i.e. remove the constraints from the deployment
   descriptor or annotations of the app)
2. write a custom Tomcat Valve to do the work of inspecting the SM http request headers and assert the J2EE principal(s) there, before the app
3. CA SSO does have a Tomcat agent which installs directly onto the Tomcat server - I've not used it in a decade so I'm not sure how well it works or if it asserts
   the J2EE principals
4. [disclosure - this is self promotion] Look at my company's CA SSO extensions that fully support J2EE in Tomcat, JBoss/Wildfly, WebSphere etc. as well as directly embedding the CA SSO enforcement into your app as a Servlet Filter:
   https://www.idfconnect.com/products/sso-rest/

HTH!